# How to close an Angular Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I´m working with Angular 4, Firebase and Angular Bootstrap. I open the modal, which is a user form, and the idea is to close the modal as soon as the user logs in using one of the methods to login (google auth, Facebook auth or email and password auth). But I can't find a way to close the modal when needed.

**google auth**

```
    export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

          @ViewChild('close') public modal: ElementRef;
    
          constructor() {}
    
    
          public openModal(content) {
            this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
              this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
            }, (reason) => {
              this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
            });
          }    
          private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
            if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
              return 'by pressing ESC';
            } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
              return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
            } else {
              return `with: ${reason}`;
            }
          }
         public googleLogin(content): void {
           this.auth.googleAuth().then((res: any) => {
              // close the modal in this moment.
              this.modal.nativeElement.click();
              const user = res.user;
              this.router.navigate(['/gallery']);
            });
         }}
```

**Modal html**

```
<ng-template #login let-c="close" let-d="dismiss" class="modal-dialog">
  <button #close type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ngb-tabset>
      <ngb-tab title="Couple">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Couple</h4>
          </div>
          <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="userlogin(user)" novalidate>
            <div id="couple_login_form" class="login-form">
              <div class="login-field" [ngClass]="{'pattern' : loginForm.controls.email.invalid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty, 'error' : loginForm.controls.email.pristine && loginForm.controls.email.touched, 'focus' : loginForm.controls.email.dirty}">
                <label for="email_login">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email">
                <div class="message text-center">
                  <p>This field is required</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pattern text-center">
                  <p>Enter a valid email.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="login-field" [ngClass]="{'error' : loginForm.controls.password.pristine && loginForm.controls.password.touched, 'focus' : loginForm.controls.password.dirty}">
                <label for="pass_login">Password</label>
                <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" formControlName="password">
                <div class="message text-center">
                  <p>This field is required</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="text-center bottom-msg-login">Don't have an account yet? Download the app für Android or iOS, <br>sign in and create your wedding!</p>
              <button class="submit" type="submit" name="couple" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="wrapper-social-login">
            <div id="google_login" (click)="googleLogin(login)"></div>
            <div id="facebook_login" (click)="facebookLogin()"></div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab title="Guests">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Guest</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="guest_login_form" class="login-form">
            <div class="login-field">
              <label for="email_login">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name">
              <div class="message text-center">
                <p>This field is required</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="login-field">
              <label for="pass_login">Wedding Code</label>
              <input type="password" name="login_code" id="login_code">
              <div class="message text-center">
                <p>This field is required</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pattern text-center">
                <p>Enter a valid code.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center bottom-msg-login">Also getting married?Take a look at our packages and create <br> your own wedding within the app!</p>
            <button class="submit" id="guest_login_btn" type="button" name="guest">Login</button>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow this step

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-modal-child',
  templateUrl: './child.html'
})
export class DemoModalChildComponent {
@ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;

public showChildModal():void {
  this.childModal.show();
}

public hideChildModal():void {
  this.childModal.hide();
 }
}

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showChildModal()">Open child modal</button>
    <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Child modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    I am a child modal, opened from parent component!
  </div>
</div>
```

[ngx-bootstrap link here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/1.9.3/#/modals)

Comment: In this case i check as answer even if is no really the answer because i was using another bootstrap module call `ng-bootstrap`  from [Angular Bootstraop](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) but changing to the ngx-bootstrap, fixed the problem so thanks any way.

Answer (score 14):

You can use ViewChild :

In your ts:

```
@ViewChild('closeModal') closeModal: ElementRef


@Component({
  ...
})
export class NameComponent extends TicketActionsModal {

  @ViewChild('closeModal') closeModal: ElementRef

  ...

}
```

When you need to close the modal you call: `this.closeModal.nativeElement.click()`

For example:

```
public googleLogin(content): void {
   this.auth.googleAuth().then((res: any) => {
      // close the modal in this moment.
      this.closeModal.nativeElement.click() //<-- here
      const user = res.user;
      this.router.navigate(['/gallery']);
   });
}
```

In your html, add `#closeModal` to the button:

```
<button #closeModal type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: i have the error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.modal.nativeElement is undefined`

Comment: modal is a viewchild in the component?

Comment: yes of course i just change the name of `closeModal` for `modal`

Comment: can you modify your question with your code? That's work for me

Comment: On the button in your html maybe you have forget to add #login in your case. You can check into my answer

Comment: Not on the ng-template :)

Comment: ok i make the change but still getting the same error, and if i remove the `#login` from the ng-template the modal doesn´t open, i gonna edit the code for you to see how is now

Comment: now what i did was to put `#close ` to the button and get on the `@viewChild('close')` and leave the ng-template with the `#login` but i still gettin the same error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.modal.nativeElement is undefined`

Comment: what's your bootstrap's version? In the latest documentation 4.0 ng-template isn't use

Comment: i´m using the `ng-bootstrap` from [Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) the last version is the 1.0.0 Beta, but im gonna change to the `ngx-bootstrap`  to see if i can do it in a easier way

Comment: Can you do a gist with your .ts and .html?

Comment: Guy Thanks so much for the help but it was much easy and fast for my just change the bootstrap module to ngx-bootstrap in this case.

Comment: In angular 8 you have to pass two parameter @ViewChild('closeModal',{static: false}) closeModal: ElementRef;

Answer (score 12):

A simple method is to hide buttons

```
  <button id="openModalButton" [hidden]="true" data-toggle="modal" data- 
   target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <button id="closeModalButton" [hidden]="true" data-toggle="modal"        
   data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default"                          
  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

myModal should be the id name of the modal.
To open the modal

```
document.getElementById("openModalButton").click();
```

To close the modal

```
document.getElementById("closeModalButton").click();
```

Answer (score 4):

Give your close button an ID

```
<button id="ModalClose" type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Then in your Typescript, you can use plain old JS

```
document.getElementById("ModalClose")?.click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Give an ID to button (Modal close cutton)

```
let elem = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

let evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });

elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 3):

use NgbModal class method "dismissall()" to close the modal

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
  )

this.modalService.dismissAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(click)="modal.close('Done')"` for the button.

For example:

In your HTML:

```
<ng-template #removeModal let-modal>
<div class="modal-header bg-primary">
    <h6 class="modal-title text-light" 
        id="deleteModalCenterTitle">
        Delete
    </h6>
</div>
<div class="modal-body mx-3">
    Are you sure?
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"
        (click)="doDelete()">
        Delete
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
        (click)="modal.close('Done click')">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div></ng-template>
```

In your component:

Start your modal with: `this.modalService.open(this.removeModal, { centered: true });`